# Unable to Edit Pages with Elementor in WordPress Docker: Side Panel Loading Indefinitely

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am encountering a problem with **WordPress Docker**. I purchased a theme from Themeforest and started a WordPress instance. Everything is working as expected. Here are the steps I follow to install the theme:

1. Install the theme zip file.
2. Install plugins needed by the theme.
3. Import demo data.

The pages are edited using the **Elementor plugin**. The pages render and work as expected. However, when I try to edit them with Elementor, I notice that **the side panel is loading indefinitely and doesn't display properly**.

[image: Side panel loading Elementor]

I am using the latest version of the **WordPress Docker image (6.2.2)** and **PHP 8.0**.

**Here's the catch: when I perform the same steps on a cloud installation of WordPress with the same versions, it works without any problems. I'm unsure what the issue could be. Any assistance would be appreciated.
When I remove the plugin that is shipped with the theme, Elementor works fine. However, it's strange that this problem is not present in the cloud installation.**

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Switching to **PHP 7.4**.
- **Increasing memory limits**.

What could be the problem?

Edit:
I am using a fresh WordPress Docker container, so no plugins are installed except those shipped with the theme.
I am using the last version of Elementor.

As I have said I tried the theme for a cloud installation with the same plugins and versions, so it's likely to be an environment problem.